# Writing data from textbox into text file

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

Here is the code im using to write and read from text file.

```
StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("DataNames.txt");
sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
sw1.Close();
StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter("DataNumbers.txt");
sw2.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
sw2.Close();
FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo("DataNames.txt");
StreamReader sr1 = file1.OpenText();
while (!sr1.EndOfStream)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(sr1.ReadLine());
}
FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo("DataNumbers.txt");
StreamReader sr2 = file2.OpenText();
while (!sr2.EndOfStream)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(sr2.ReadLine());
}
```

The thing is that when I click my button to save data from my textboxes to my text files an error appears that says "The process cannot access the file 'C:\xxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx.txt' because it is being used by another process."

Can anyone tell me why I have this error and maybe help me fix it

Answer (score 4):

Try added a `using` statment around your streams to make sure they are `Disposed` otherwise the file is still locked to the stream

Example:

```
   //Write
    using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("DataNames.txt"))
    {
        sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter("DataNumbers.txt"))
    {
        sw2.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
    }


    // Read
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("DataNames.txt"))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("DataNumbers.txt"))
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(line);
    }
```

Comment: This is by far a much better solution there is no need to use a While loop when you can use the `File.ReadAllLines` Method

Answer (score 3):

It appears you do not close the file after you read it. After you call [FileInfo.OpenText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext.aspx) you get a `StreamReader` which has to be closed, either via [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx) method, or even better, with a `using` statement.

But there are already methods that do all that for you, have a look at [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx),
[File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) and [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx) the StreamReader object once you do not need it any more.  This should fix this issue.
I.e.

```
StreamReader sr1 = file1.OpenText();
try {
            while (!sr1.EndOfStream)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(sr1.ReadLine());
            }
}
finally { 
  sr1.Close();
}
            FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo("DataNumbers.txt");
            StreamReader sr2 = file2.OpenText();
try {
            while (!sr2.EndOfStream)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(sr2.ReadLine());
            }
}
finally {
  sr2.Close();
}
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, yes, it is also possible to use using, since the StreamReader implements IDisposable.  The sense is absolutely the same and the Dispose calls the Close method inside...

Answer (score 1):

You have opened files but not closed.

```
StreamReader sr1 = file1.OpenText();
StreamReader sr2 = file2.OpenText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs, because you are not closing the stream readers.

A safer way of using external resources (the files in this case) is to embed their use in a `using` statement. The `using` statement automatically closes the resource at the end of the statement block or if the statement block if left in another way. This could be a `return` statement or an exception, for instance. It is guaranteed that the resource will be closed, even after an exception occurs.

You can apply the `using` statement on any object which implements the `IDisposable` interface.

```
// Writing to the files
using (var sw1 = new StreamWriter("DataNames.txt")) {
    sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
using(var sw2 = new StreamWriter("DataNumbers.txt")) {
    sw2.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
}

// Reading from the files
FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo("DataNames.txt");
using (StreamReader sr1 = file1.OpenText()) {
    while (!sr1.EndOfStream) {
        listBox1.Items.Add(sr1.ReadLine());
    }
}
FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo("DataNumbers.txt");
using (StreamReader sr2 = file2.OpenText()) {
    while (!sr2.EndOfStream)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(sr2.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

However, you can simplify the reading part like this

```
// Reading from the files
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("DataNames.txt"));
listBox2.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("DataNumbers.txt"));
```

Comment: +1 for some comprehensible infos about the `using`-statement. I'm just missing some words about the `File` methods like [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before - usually there's another process open that's blocking the file access. Do you have multiple development servers open in your taskbar? (Strange, yes, but I've seen it happen)

Comment: yes yes sorry guys its becuase i havent closed it i knew this is the problem but i have tried to close the file1 and file2 where i need to close sr1 and sr2

Comment: @BorisTheBlade look at `sa_ddam213` solution it's more optimized as well as more readable in my opinion and it should be something that you can easily follow moving forward. happy coding